# Xamarin Forms SQLite instance crash

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm learning about Xamarin Forms, FreshMVVM and SQLite. I'll give my best to explain the issue.

I'm trying to implement simple Login/Register pages. So far I've followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases) Microsoft documentation. I do understand that the problem is when I call **await UserDatabase.Instance** in **LoginPageModel.cs**, the application just freeze and I am unable to understand why. But please take a note that when I try to call **await UserDatabase.Instance** in **RegisterPageModel.cs** it works as intended. Only when I try to call it in **LoginModelPage.cs** it crashes

**UserDatabase.cs**

```
public class UserDatabase
    {
        private static SQLiteAsyncConnection Database;

        public static readonly AsyncLazy<UserDatabase> Instance = new AsyncLazy<UserDatabase>(async () =>
        {
            var instance = new UserDatabase();
            CreateTableResult result = await Database.CreateTableAsync<User>();
            return instance;
        });

        public UserDatabase()
        {
            Database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Constants.DatabasePath, Constants.Flags);
        }

        public Task<User> LogInUserAsync(string username, string password)
        {
            return Database.Table<User>().Where(x => x.UserName == username && x.Password == password).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }

        public Task<int> SaveUserAsync(User user)
        {
            if (user.UserId != 0)
            {
                return Database.UpdateAsync(user);
            }
            else
            {
                return Database.InsertAsync(user);
            }
        }
}
```

And I have **LoginPage.cs** and **RegisterPage.cs**:

**RegisterPageModel.cs**

```
 public class RegisterPageModel : FreshBasePageModel
    {
        public Command RegisterCommand { get; }

        public string UsernameEntry { get; set; }

        public string PasswordEntry { get; set; }

        public string ConfirmPasswordEntry { get; set; }

        public RegisterPageModel()
        {
            RegisterCommand = new Command(() =>
            {
                // if passwords does not match, show alert. Otherwise register user.
                if (PasswordEntry == ConfirmPasswordEntry)
                {
                    User = new User
                    {
                        UserName = UsernameEntry,
                        Password = PasswordEntry
                    };
                    SaveUser(User);

                    CoreMethods.PushPageModel<LoginPageModel>();
                }
                else
                {
                    Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Try again", "Passwords does not match!", "Ok");
                }
            });
        }

        private async void SaveUser(User user)
        {
            UserDatabase database = await UserDatabase.Instance;
            await database.SaveUserAsync(user);
        }
}
```

**LoginPageModel.cs**

```
public class LoginPageModel : FreshBasePageModel
    {
        public Command RegisterCommand { get; }

        public string UsernameEntry { get; set; }

        public string PasswordEntry { get; set; }

        public Command LoginCommand { get; set; }

        public LoginPageModel()
        {
            // When we press Register button, redirect us to the register page
            RegisterCommand = new Command(() =>
            {
                CoreMethods.PushPageModel<RegisterPageModel>();
            });

            // When we press on Login button login user and redirect to the main page
            LoginCommand = new Command(() =>
            {
                if (LoginUser().Result)
                {
                    CoreMethods.PushPageModel<MainPageModel>();
                }
                else
                {
                    Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Login Failed", "Incorrect Username or Password!", "Ok");
                }

            });
        }

        private async Task<bool> LoginUser()
        {
            UserDatabase database = await UserDatabase.Instance;
            User user = await database.LogInUserAsync(UsernameEntry, PasswordEntry);
            if (user == null)
            {
                // store Userdetails
                Application.Current.Properties["UserDetail"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);

                // Set it to true 
                Application.Current.Properties["IsLoggedIn"] = bool.TrueString;

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: does it freeze or does it crash?  Or freeze then eventually crash?  Is there an exception thrown?  Have you tried adding any exception handling, or stepping through the code in the debugger?

Comment: When I try to Login, it freezes. I tried to put try, Cache block, in hope to get an exception out, but nothing was triggered.. I did try to debug the code, and when I got to the ```await UserDatabase.Instance``` in **LoginPageModel.cs** it jsut step out. But what I do not understand is, why that same call worked well with RegisterUser, but it crashed with LoginUser :(

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue I needed to change **LoginUser** Method

From this:

```
        private async Task<bool> LoginUser()
        {
            UserDatabase database = await UserDatabase.Instance;
            User user = await database.LogInUserAsync(UsernameEntry, PasswordEntry);
            if (user == null)
            {
                // store Userdetails
                Application.Current.Properties["UserDetail"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);

                // Set it to true 
                Application.Current.Properties["IsLoggedIn"] = bool.TrueString;

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

To this:

```
        private async void LoginUser()
        {
            UserDatabase database = await UserDatabase.Instance;
            User user = await database.LogInUserAsync(UsernameEntry, PasswordEntry);
            if (user == null)
            {
                // store Userdetails
                Application.Current.Properties["UserDetail"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);

                // Set it to true 
                Application.Current.Properties["IsLoggedIn"] = bool.TrueString;
            }
            else
            {
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Login Failed", "Incorrect Username or Password!", "Ok");
            }
        }
```